# ¿Cómo puedo fusionar una rama secundaria en la rama principal en Git?

Tags: git, control-de-versiones, ramas-git

Estoy aprendiendo Git y tengo una pregunta sobre la fusión de ramas. He creado una rama secundaria para trabajar en una nueva característica y ahora quiero fusionar esos cambios en la rama principal. ¿Cuáles son los pasos específicos que debo seguir para realizar esta fusión de manera correcta?

He intentado buscar información en la documentación de Git, pero me gustaría obtener una explicación más detallada y posiblemente ejemplos concretos. También, ¿existen consideraciones importantes que debo tener en cuenta antes de realizar la fusión?

Comment: Aunque ya hay una respuesta apropiada (ya le hice upvote), creo que este libro es buenísimo: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-B%C3%A1sicos-para-Ramificar-y-Fusionar

Comment: @eftshift0 Gracias por el apoyo con el upvote. Tienes razón, de la página oficial y esta también muy bien explicado. Gracias por tu aporte.,

Comment: muchas gracias por las respuestas

Comment: @NicolasOjeda si te sirve la respuesta, dale like y márcala como aceptada para que otras personas con el mismo problema puedan verla más rápidamente.

Answer (score -1):

El comando que buscas es [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) añadiéndole la rama que quieres fusionar, quedando así: `git merge rama-que-mergear`.

Antes de hacer esto debes colocarte en la rama a la cual quieres mergear (fusionar, como lo llamas tú) la rama. Para hacer esto tienes que ejecutar el comando [`git checkout nombre-rama`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Es decir, primero te colocas en la rama mediante `git checkout` y después mergeas (fusionas) la rama que quieres con `git merge`.

Te dejo un [link de una web](https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge) en español que, a mi parecer, lo explica de una forma sencilla y con imágenes para que sea sencillo verlo. Esta web también explica otros comandos y el funcionamiento de GIT.

Por otro lado, en cuanto a cosas a tener en cuenta, pues hay un par de cosas básicas a tener en cuenta. Algunas pueden ser que no hayas modificado el mismo archivo en ramas diferentes, porque esto puede darte conflictos que tendrás que resolver manualmente.

Ánimo con GIT, es una herramienta muy potente y un must en el desarrollo de hoy en día. Tienes mil foros, mil videos y mil cursos en internet que te explican el funcionamiento de GIT, te recomiendo echarles un ojo.